# Modern Fortran: Calling an ancestor procedure from descendent

Tags: fortran

I am starting to use the OO features of Modern Fortran and am already familiar with OO in other languages. In Delphi (Object Pascal) it is common to call an ancestor version of a procedure in its overridden descendent procedure and there is even a language statement "inherited" that allows this. I can't find an equivalent Fortran construct - but am probably looking for the wrong thing. See simple example below. Any advice much appreciated.

```
type tClass
  integer :: i
contains
  procedure Clear => Clear_Class
end type tClass

type tSubClass
  integer :: j
contains
  procedure Clear => Clear_SubClass
end type tSubClass

subroutine Clear_Class
  i = 0
end subroutine

subroutine Clear_SubClass
  inherited Clear ! this is the Delphi way
  j = 0
end subroutine
```

Comment: It's not obvious in much of the 'literature' on Fortran's derived-type capabilities, but, in your example, `SubClass` has a component called `Class` and you can call  procedures bound to that component, so something like `call SubClass%Class%Clear(args)` (replacing, of course, the type names by the names of instances of the type).  See, for example, https://gist.github.com/n-s-k/522f2669979ed6d0582b8e80cf6c95fd, maybe even other Qs and As here on SO.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark 4.5.7.2#2 of ISO 1539-1:2010 *"An extended type has a scalar, nonpointer, nonallocatable, parent component with the type and type parameters of the parent type. The name of this component is the parent type name."*

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: yes, I know.  But I can't quote the standard verbatim as you can !

Comment: Thanks Mark - that will do the job perfectly. Strange that it is not highlighted more in the literature. I would have thought (from my Delphi experience) that it is a very common usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some sample code that tries to implement the comment by @HighPerformanceMark (i.e., a child type has a hidden component that refers to the parent type).

```
module testmod
    implicit none

    type tClass
        integer :: i = 123
    contains
        procedure :: Clear => Clear_Class
    endtype

    type, extends(tClass) :: tSubClass
        integer :: j = 456
    contains
        procedure :: Clear => Clear_SubClass
    endtype

contains

    subroutine Clear_Class( this )
        class(tClass) :: this
        this % i = 0
    end

    subroutine Clear_SubClass( this )
        class(tSubClass) :: this
        this % j = 0
        call this % tClass % Clear()  !! (*) calling a method of the parent type
    end
end

program main
    use testmod
    implicit none
    type(tClass) :: foo
    type(tSubClass) :: subfoo

    print *, "foo (before) = ", foo
    call foo % Clear()
    print *, "foo (after)  = ", foo

    print *, "subfoo (before) = ", subfoo
    call subfoo % Clear()
    print *, "subfoo (after)  = ", subfoo
end
```

which gives (with gfortran-8.2)

```
 foo (before) =          123
 foo (after)  =            0
 subfoo (before) =          123         456
 subfoo (after)  =            0           0
```

If we comment out the line marked by (*), `subfoo % i` is kept unmodified:

```
 foo (before) =          123
 foo (after)  =            0
 subfoo (before) =          123         456
 subfoo (after)  =          123           0
```

Comment: Thanks. Just what I needed - sorry for missing the explicit declaration of the "this" argument. In my defence I am used to Delphi where the "self" argument is hidden/implicit and always available in methods.